# Sublassing UITableViewCell and using it in a Storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am testing a customized UITableViewCell where the pieces are customized in initWithStyle and the controls are created in code. I am testing to see whether what we can use this cell with storyboards and prototype cells in a UITableView and use the interactions provided by storyboard. The cell that I'm using is called EvenCell.

If I remove the prototype cell and instantiate the cell in code like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    EvenCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    if(cell==nil)
        cell=[[EvenCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

    cell.cellTitleLabel.text=[allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

it works.

[image]

But when I set up a prototype cell and set it's class to EvenCell and reuse identifier to "MyCell", it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong or is what I'm trying to do possible?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that there's actually any data sent to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? If you put `NSLog(@"hey ho");` in that method, is it printing out anything? Or am I misunderstanding your question? Are you asking why it doesn't show up in the simulator, or why the prototype in storyboard doesn't look like your custom cell?

Comment: Why it doesn't show up in the Simulator? It seems like if we specify in the prototype cell that it's class is EvenCell then when we call initWithStyle, it should render correctly as the first example does. It seems like the prototype cell just doesn't really recognize the custom cell upon which it is based. I am trying to see if we can reuse this cell that has already been created. thx

Comment: Ok, but are you sure the tableview is still using the delegate/dataSource methods? Have you verified that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called? Maybe you should post your `initWithStyle` too..

Comment: Did you confirm that iniWithStyle is called -- if I remember correctly, it isn't called. You should just setup your views in IB like user1873508 suggested.

Comment: I'd really like to be able to reuse these custom table view cell classes - they seem to provide the most power in laying things out.

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly, you have empty cell in second example. You need to add subviews to your cell content in interface builder and connect it as outlets with your EvenCell class. For example: Add Label to your custom cell in interface builder, than make an outlet in EvenCell class for that label, you can name outlet for ex. titleLabel and than in your tableview:cellForRowAtIndexPath set your label text property by cell.titleLabel.text = [allKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]

I've just spotted that I missed part about adding new views to cell content in initWithStyle method. So I've just created example code in xCode and it worked for me even if cell subviews are added programatically in EvenCell initWithStyle method. This is example:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface EvenCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *textLabel;
@end

#import "EvenCell.h"

@implementation EvenCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    self.textLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 20)];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.textLabel];

}
return self;}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

than In your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method

```
 -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellId = @"MyCell";

EvenCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[testCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellId];
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Example title";

return cell;
}
```

And in interface builder set dynamic prototypes cells for UITableView, set cell class to EvenCell and set cell identifier to MyCell and it has to work. I've just check it.

Comment: so I'm trying to really just reuse the table view that has already been written. It seems like once we use that UITableView, we can't use storyboard features below.

Comment: where do you set dynamic properties?

Comment: click on the TableView in interface builder and than it is first property in attributes inspector: Content. It may be static cells or dynamic cells

Comment: but I see from your interface builder screenshots that you have dynamic prototypes set. If it is not working for you be sure to check that delegates are set properly. Right click on tableView and than you will see if your delegates are connected.

Comment: Yeah, hmmm ... let me look through your example some more and see what I'm doing wrong. This might just be a bad idea on my part to try to reuse this code.

Comment: should the cellForRowAtIndexPath be using EvenCell rather than testCell?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to change it before i've past it

Comment: So I think you're just setting the default textLabel. If you NSLog(@"here in initWithStyle"); in your initWithStyle, is it logged? For me, it wasn't.